# Piezoelectric disks gives higher output at a particular low frequency far from the resonant frequency?

Tags: piezo-buzzer, resonant

I have a [PZT disk](https://assets.rs-online.com/v1699613488/Datasheets/a4bec9145cc21cbb98424742258b4039.pdf) attached to a shaker/vibration generator. The resonant frequency is 3.9kHz.

The following is the output of the PZT disk on the shaker, being shook at different frequencies.

[image]

One observed event is the anomaly at 47Hz. I am unsure why the output of the PZT would greatly increase around that area.

This is the output of the PZT disk attached to a charge amplifier with a cut-off of 72Hz.
[image]

One theory I have is additional vibrations are introduced by the shaker, which could reach 3.9kHz around 47Hz. However, I am unsure what other elements could be causing this.

Please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: Have you established that the signal at 47 Hz isn't from mains wiring? Have you ensured that there isn't a mechanical resonance in the shaker itself at 47 Hz? You need to drive your shaker in a controlled manner using a recognized mechanical accelerator in a feedback loop to ensure there are no resonances as you sweep through frequencies. If you don't do that you get false results like in your table.

Comment: How is it attached to the shaker? Resonances depend on the whole system, not just dimensions of the disc by itself.